# Why `filter` works for one list and not for other giving "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous."?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following helper functions:

```
flatten = lambda sentences : [word for sentence in sentences for word in sentence] # flattens list of lists 
get_feature = lambda f, input: np.array(list(map(f, input))) # applies f() to each element of input list and returns list of resultant elements
is_numeric = lambda words: get_feature(lambda word: word.isnumeric(), words)
```

Then doing following:

```
ls = ['a','1','b','2','c','d','e']
print(type(ls))
print(list(filter(is_numeric, ls)))
print(type(train_tokens))
print(train_tokens[:10])
print(list(filter(is_numeric, train_tokens))[:10])
```

gives following output:

```
<class 'list'>
['1', '2']
<class 'list'>
['EU', 'rejects', 'German', 'call', 'to', 'boycott', 'British', 'lamb', '.', 'Peter']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-59836dbfb218> in <module>()
     11 print(type(train_tokens))
     12 print(train_tokens[:10])
---> 13 print(list(filter(is_numeric, train_tokens))[:10])

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Both `ls` and `train_tokens` are lists. Then I dont get why `filter` works for `ls` but not for `train_tokens`.

What stupid mistake I am doing?

**PS:** This is how I formed `train_tokens`:

```
!pip install datasets
from datasets import load_dataset
conll2003dataset = load_dataset("conll2003")

train_tokens = flatten(conll2003dataset['train']['tokens'])
```

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aeTE3O1_fH1jpSxxYvlb_io8_2pgFK_e?usp=sharing) is the link to the notebook.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood how the `filter` function works. It expects a function that will be called on each element of the input iterable, and if the function returns a truthy value, it yields that value in its output. You seem to be doing operations that would make more sense when applied to the whole list, not to an individual element. It's being masked a bit because strings are iterable. The error occurs because `train_tokens` contains multi-character strings, while the strings in `ls` are all only one-character long.

Answer (score 0):

The function you're using with `filter` doesn't do what it's expected to do. `filter` applies the function to each element of its input iterable one at a time. With your function, that means you're checking each *character* of the word to see if it is numeric, and returning a `boolean` numpy array. That array works with `filter` only if it is length 1. That is, if there was only one letter in the word. For longer words, you get longer arrays, and as the error message says, you can't evaluate a numpy array of length greater than one in a boolean context.

If you really want to use `filter`, you don't actually need to write your own functions (certainly not any that are as complicated as what you've shown). Just pass `str.isnumeric` as the function and it will check the whole word in one go (not letter by letter).

```
print(list(filter(str.isnumeric, train_tokens)))
```

On the other hand, if you do really want to use `numpy` and your own numeric checking code, you could give up on `filter` and call your `is_numeric` lambda function *on the whole list* to get a boolean numpy array that you can use as a mask. If you convert the input into an array too, you could index into it with the mask to get just the numeric entries:

```
numeric_mask = is_numeric(train_tokens)   # this is calling your function is_numeric
train_tokens_array = np.asarray(train_tokens)
print(train_tokens_array[numeric_mask][:10])
```